# Read csv files with quotes with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have troubles to read correctly a csv file with pandas. I've already search a solution to my issue, but I didn't find one.

So, my file contains informations about tracks, but the structure of it is a bit special. This is the header structure, and most of the rows respect it.

```
artist, trackname, albumname, tracknum, year, mp3genre
Anton Cosmo, Cry, The In Between, 12, 2010, Electro Rock
```

But some rows have a different structure like this one :

```
artist, trackname, albumname, tracknum, year, mp3genre
Anne Garner, "Home, Outbound","Long Journey Here, 1, 2011, Electronica
```

I've tried many ways to read this csv file into a pandas DataFrame but I didn't succeed. I thought that:

```
df = pd.read_csv("songs.csv", quotechar="\"")
```

would work but it gives me a line like this one :

```
artist                                Anne Garner
trackname    "Home, Outbound" , Long Journey Here
albumname                                       1
tracknum                                     2011
year                                  Electronica
mp3genre                                      NaN
```

instead of :

```
artist                                Anne Garner
trackname                          Home, Outbound
albumname                       Long Journey Here                   
tracknum                                        1
year                                         2011
mp3genre                              Electronica
```

Do you know a way to do this reading properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this truly the structure? you have a quote that never finishes. at "Long Journey Here...

Comment: Indeed I made a mistake, the real structure is
"Anne Garner",""Home, Outbound"","Long Journey Here","1","2011","Electronica"

Comment: So you have `""Home, Outbound""` 'unquoted'? Two quotes in the beginning and end of the string?

Comment: You could try to replace every occurence of `""` for `"`.

Comment: The method mentioned by @joaoavf is worth a try, but there is no guarantee it is going to work unless you know `""` dos not appears in any of the fields. If you control the production of the file you try to parse you could avoid writing double quotes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you could try replacing the `""` with `"` whilst reading. One approach would be to use a `csv.reader()` to pre-parse the data before passing it to Pandas. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

with open('songs.csv') as f_input:
    data = [next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(line.replace('""', '"')))) for line in f_input]

print(pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]))
```

This would give you:

```
        artist       trackname          albumname tracknum   year      mp3genre
0  Anton Cosmo             Cry     The In Between       12   2010  Electro Rock
1  Anne Garner  Home, Outbound  Long Journey Here        1   2011   Electronica
```